Pass any Action as Generic Parameter for type
So I was making callbacks, and sometimes I need two of them: Before and After, so I was trying to wrap them into a structure:
public struct DoubleAction<T> where T : System.Delegate
{
    public DoubleAction()
    {
        Before = delegate { };
        After = delegate { };
    }

    public T Before;
    public T After;
}

// example usage:

DoubleAction<Action<int, string>> OnWrite;

But Action, Action<T1>, etc. didn't have parents, so I can't limit type T and create empty delegates automatically (didn't want to ?. each time for Action? + its more performance usage when used frequently)
So I came up with only that solution:
make a lot of DoubleAction types for every Action type:
public struct DoubleAction<T>
{
    public DoubleAction()
    {
        Before = delegate { };
        After = delegate { };
    }

    public Action<T> Before;
    public Action<T> After;
}

public struct DoubleAction<T1, T2> { ... }
public struct DoubleAction<T1, T2, T3> { ... }
public struct DoubleAction<T1, T2, T3, T4> { ... }
public struct DoubleAction<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5> { ... }
// and so on

Is there any way to make it more clean?

Btw with this solution i can't use custom defined delegates instead of Action's (so i losing some helpful argument naming)

We can use a bit of reflection and dynamically build a LambdaExpression<TAction> based on the TAction signature. Also we get a void check in the process to ensure we are dealing with Action (but we can deal with any void-returning method as opposed to your initial manual implementation).
To speed things up, we cache the value of the compiled empty delegate instance in a static field (as suggested by
jilles in a comment). The solution can be modified to be used for any delegate (not just Action) easily too - see comments in the code:
public struct DoubleAction<TAction>
where TAction : Delegate {
    public TAction Before;
    public TAction After;

    public DoubleAction() {
        var emptyDelegate = s_EmptyDelegate;
        // remove check if you want TAction to be TDelegate
        // of any type
        if (emptyDelegate == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Non void delegate");
        }
        Before = emptyDelegate;
        After = emptyDelegate;
    }

    static readonly TAction s_EmptyDelegate = CreateDelegate();

    static TAction CreateDelegate() {
        var invokeMethod = typeof(TAction).GetMethod("Invoke");
        var returnType = invokeMethod.ReturnType;

        // remove check if you want TAction to be TDelegate
        // of any type
        if (returnType != typeof(void)) {
            return null;
        }

        var paramExpressions = invokeMethod
             .GetParameters()
             .Select(x => Expression.Parameter(x.ParameterType));

        var exp = Expression.Lambda<TAction>(
            body: Expression.Default(returnType),
            parameters: paramExpressions);

        return exp.Compile();
    }
}

The original caching solution used (in a somewhat hacky proof of concept way) a ConcurrentDictionary for caching which on reflection didn't make sense as we have an open generic type, so we'll have a dictionary with one entry per DoubleAction<concreteType>. The next solution used to initialize the static field in a static constructor but that incurred some performance penalties as noted by OP in a comment - more info in this answer.
With the caching during static field initialization from above we get some performance improvements (not penalties) over the original version as tested on .NET 6:
BenchMarkNew       11.68 μs 11.66 μs 11.69 μs 0% 0 983,040 Complete 
BenchMarkOriginal  15.15 μs 15.11 μs 15.21 μs 1% 0 917,504 Complete 

Benchmarking code:
public void BenchMarkNew() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        var del = new DoubleAction<Action<int>>();
    }
}

public void BenchMarkOriginal() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        var del = new DoubleActionOriginal<Action<int>>();
    }
}


As Cache is a ConcurrentDictionary your code that does if (Cache.ContainsKey(tActionType)) { is not safe for concurrency - you need to use GetOrAdd here - in fact, most of this logic should be moved into an atomic value factory function for Cache, imo.

@Dai Well, I thought about it. Maybe, it's getting late, but I don't think we run into real problems with this naive/wrong implementation. What's the worst that can happen now?

"What's the worst that can happen now?" - An unhandled-exception caused by a difficult-to-diagnose race-condition at runtime.

@Dai okay,okay...editing

An alternative to the DoubleActionCache class would be private static readonly TAction EmptyDelegate = CreateCachedValue(typeof(TAction)) inside DoubleAction<TAction>.

To much performance usage sadly

I get 20-25% slower times with this mainly due to the if Action check. If we can have any delegate, we are 5-6x faster.

@ШвеевАлексей switched to using static field initialization instead of static constructor which did improve things significantly. Check the updated answer.
